# Python list of objects vs list of primitives

Tags: python, list, object

Following is the MWE:

```py
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.data)

object_list = [Foo(10), Foo(80), Foo(50), Foo(60), Foo(20)]
int_list = [10, 80, 50, 60, 20]

print("Object list before modification:  {}".format(object_list))
print("Integer list before modification: {}".format(int_list))

for i in object_list:
    i.data += 5

for j in int_list:
    j += 5

print("")
print("Object list after modification:   {}".format(object_list))
print("Integer list after modification:  {}".format(int_list))
```

The output is as follows:

```
Object list before modification:  [10, 80, 50, 60, 20]
Integer list before modification: [10, 80, 50, 60, 20]

Object list after modification:   [15, 85, 55, 65, 25]
Integer list after modification:  [10, 80, 50, 60, 20]
```

Why are the results different? In my opinion, the integer result seems more natural as we are not exactly performing the operation on the list (like `for idx in range(len(object_list)): object_list[idx].data += 5`). We are rather applying it on the elements after we take them out.

Comment: **Python doesn't have primitives**. Everything is an object. *everything*. Including `int` objects.

Comment: Anyway, this is simple. In one case, you have mutable objects in your list, `Foo`, and you *mutate the object*, `i.data += 5` will mutate the `Foo` object being referenced by `i`. In the second case, you have an immutable object, an `int`, and `j += 5` *creates a new int object and assigns it to `j`*

Comment: "We are rather applying it on the elements after we take them out." Sure, but the objects haven't been removed from the list, they are still being referenced in the list.

Comment: I suggest you to make a search about why increment operator "++" doesn't work in Python.

Comment: @user70 What do you mean? `++` in other languages is short for `+=1`, no?

Comment: Relevant docs: [Objects, values and types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types), [Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)

Comment: @wjandrea only "++" prefix can work in Python and this indicates only that the variable is positive; "++" suffix gives syntax error. `i+=1` and `i=i+1` works in Python, but Python integers are immutable, handling integers are not the same in every language.

Comment: @user70 How is that related to the question?

Comment: @wjandrea '++' is not related the question, but why it's not working in Python is related to this question

Answer (score 1):

This is the strangeness of augmented assignment. "+=" takes three steps: 1) get the value from the left hand side, 2) add the value on the right hand side 3) store the result back in the variable on the left hand side.

In your first case, the left hand side is `i.data` and `i.data` is reassigned to the result. Since the object in `i` is in the original list, its reassigned attribute "data" shows the change.

In your second case, the left hand side is `j`. It us updated properly, but since `j` isn't saved anywhere, its value is lost.